# Scraping a paginated website: Scraping page 2 gives back page 1 results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using the get method of the requests library in python to scrape information from a website which is organized into pages (i.e paginated with numbers at the bottom).

Page 1 link: https://realfood.tesco.com/search.html?DietaryOption=Vegetarian

I am able to extract the data that I need from the first page but when I feed my code the url for the second page, I get the same data from the first page. Now after carefully analyzing my code, I am certain the issue is not my code logic but the way the second page url is structured.

So my question is how can I get my code to work as I want. I suspect it is a question of parameters but I am not 100% percent sure. If indeed it is parameters that I need to pass to request, I would appreciate some guidance on how to break down the parameters. My page 2 link is attached below.
Thanks.

Page 2 link: https://realfood.tesco.com/search.html?DietaryOption=Vegetarian#!q='selectedobjecttype%3DRECIPES%26page%3D2%26perpage%3D30%26DietaryOption%3DVegetarian'

Note: The pages are not really links per se.

Comment: try to use selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

for numb in ('1', '10'):
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://realfood.tesco.com/search.html?DietaryOption=Vegetarian")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(link['href'])
```

Hopefully it works for you.  I can't test it because my office blocks these kinds of things.  I'll try it when I get home tonight to see if it does what it should do...

Comment: I'll try and up vote you if it works. Thanks. I had used one of the solutions above.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like platform is ASP.NET and pagination links are operated by JS. I seriously doubt you will have it easy with python, since beautifulsoup is a HTML parser/extractor, so if you really want to use this site, I would suggest to looking into Selenium or even PhantomJS, since they fully replicate the browser.

But in this particular case you are lucky, because there's a legacy website version which doesn't use modern bells and whistles :)

http://legacy.realfood.tesco.com/recipes/search.html?st=vegetarian&cr=False&page=3&srt=searchRelevance

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit familiar with selenium. I will try it. I thought the issue was I wasn't passing parameters. May I ask how you found the old website?

Comment: curious - what would you then use other than python?

Comment: This maybe be a silly statement but isn't selenium a Python module? This is the part where I add that I only know Selenium in theory. I know it has a Webdriver which can be used to access page elements. Will that help me grab the data?

Comment: @erocar PhantomJS is a node module, so JS is another option for live website parsing (e.g. with respect to working scripts). If you want to stick to Python, use Selenium Webdriver, which is actually a wrapper for Firefox (don't sure about current Chrome support status), and it allows you to programatically click on elements from real browser. Actually you can use your existing solution with this legacy site, just adapt selector names etc. I found it by just random clicking around :)

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Myself I'll stick with Python.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the pagination of this site is handled by the query parameters passed in the second URL you posted, ie:

```
https://realfood.tesco.com/search.html?DietaryOption=Vegetarian#!q='selectedobjecttype%3DRECIPES%26page%3D2%26perpage%3D30%26DietaryOption%3DVegetarian'
```

The query string is url encoded. %3D is = and %26 is &. It might be more readable like this:

```
q='selectedobjecttype=RECIPES&page=2&perpage=30&DietaryOption=Vegetarian'
```

For example, if you wanted to pull back the fifth page of Vegetarian Recipes the URL would look like this:

https://realfood.tesco.com/search.html?DietaryOption=Vegetarian#!q='selectedobjecttype%3DRECIPES%26page%3D5%26perpage%3D30%26DietaryOption%3DVegetarian'

You can keep incrementing the page number until you get a page with no results which looks like [this](https://realfood.tesco.com/search.html?DietaryOption=Vegetarian#!q='selectedobjecttype%3DRECIPES%26page%3D500%26perpage%3D30%26DietaryOption%3DVegetarian').

Comment: Okay. Sorry I saw the answer a bit late. This seems simple enough. So the url is using a different kind of encoding. I will try it using the new format and give a response. Is there a link you can share to help read more on that? Thanks

Comment: What I am curious to know is why passing the link in its current form wasn't working and whether passing it in its new form might work? I guess I will have to find out after trying. Kindly share any link (if available to elaborate more on the encoding you mentioned).